# Higher order programming with Lisp: Passing a function to mapcar?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm just learning ANSI Common Lisp (using clisp on a Win32 machine) and I was wondering if mapcar could use a function passed in as a formal argument? Please see the following:

```
(defun foo (fn seq) 
    (mapcar #'fn seq))
```

This would, in my opinion, provide a greater level of flexibility than:

```
(defun mult (i)
    (* i 2))

(defun foo ()
    (mapcar #'mult '(1 2 3)))
```

Answer (score 38):

This is absolutely possible! You're almost there. You just bumped into Common Lisp's dual namespaces, which can take a lot of getting used to. I hope I can say a thing or two to make Common Lisp's two namespaces a bit less confusing.

Your code is almost correct. You wrote:

```
(defun foo (fn seq) 
    (mapcar #'fn seq))
```

But, what is that trying to do? Well, *#'* is shorthand. I'll expand it out for you.

```
(defun foo (fn seq) 
    (mapcar (function fn) seq))
```

So, *#'symbol* is shorthand for *(function symbol)*. In Common Lisp -- as you seem to know -- symbols can be bound to a function and to a variable; these are the two namespaces that Lispers talk so much about: the function namespace, and the variable namespace.

Now, what the *function* special form does is get the function bound to a symbol, or, if you like, the value that the symbol has in the function namespace.

Now, on the REPL, what you wrote would be obviously what you want.

```
(mapcar #'car sequence)
```

Would map the *car* function to a sequence of lists. And the *car* symbol has no variable binding, only a function binding, which is why you need to use *(function ...)* (or its shorthand, *#'*) to get at the actual function.

Your *foo* function doesn't work because the function you pass it as an argument is being bound to a symbol *as a variable*. Try this:

```
(let ((fn #'sqrt))
    (mapcar #'fn '(4 9 16 25)))
```

You might have expected a list of all those numbers' square roots, but it didn't work. That's because you used *let* to bind the square root function to *fn* as a variable. Now, try this code:

```
(let ((fn #'sqrt))
    (mapcar fn '(4 9 16 25)))
```

Delightful! This binds the square root function to the *fn* symbol as a variable.

So, let's go revise your *foo* function:

```
(defun foo (fn seq) 
    (mapcar fn seq))
```

That *will* work, because *fn* is a variable. Let's test it, just to make sure:

```
;; This will not work
(foo sqrt '(4 9 16 25))
;; This will work
(foo #'sqrt '(4 9 16 25))
```

The first one didn't work, because the square root function is bound to *sqrt* in the function namespace. So, in the second one, we grabbed the function from the symbol, and passed it to foo, which bound it to the symbol *fn* as a variable.

---

Okay, so what if you want to bind a function to a symbol in the function namespace? Well, for starters, *defun* does that, permanently. If you want it to be temporary, like a *let* binding, use *flet*. *Flet* is, in my opinion, stupid, because it doesn't work exactly like let does. But, I'll give an example, just so you can see.

```
(flet ((fn (x) (sqrt x)))
    (mapcar fn '(4 9 16 25)))
```

will not work, because *flet* didn't bind the function to the symbol in the variable namespace, but in the function namespace.

```
(flet ((fn (x) (sqrt x)))
    (mapcar #'fn '(4 9 16 25)))
```

This will do what you expect, because *flet* bound that function to the symbol *fn* in the function namespace. And, just to drive the idea of the function namespace home:

```
(flet ((fn (x) (sqrt x)))
    (fn 16))
```

Will return 4.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do this:

```
(defun foo (fn)
  (mapcar fn '(1 2 3)))
```

Examples:

```
(foo #'(lambda (x) (* x 2)))
(foo #'1+)
(foo #'sqrt)
(foo #'(lambda (x) (1+ (* x 3))))
```

Comment: Great short answer